# How can I integrate React-Redux with Firebase?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux

I created a react app using `create-react-app` and configured a redux store with reducers. I also added firebase and my project works fine. The components can trigger an action that fetches a collection from firestore, and it in return, updates the redux store.

What is the best way to integrate firebase and redux store?
The way I am currently doing it, is to have a separate action that triggers the fetch/delete/onSnapshot from firebase, and handing a reference to `dispatch` so that firebase function can take its time executing the command, then it can call dispatch with an action that updates the store.

But I wanted all of my actions in a single file, for a better (separation of concerns). Therefor, firebase can call dispatch but the action creator lives in my actions.js file. This way, I can later decide to change the action names in a single file, if I decided to do that.

The problem with this approach, is I will require a separate action to trigger the async function with firebase, and another action creator for when the promise is fulfilled.

What is a better approach to what I am doing?

## store.js

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    cards: cardsReducer,
});

const store = createStore( rootReducer , {}, applyMiddleware(thunk));
export default store;
```

## myFirebase.js

```
// I need this to be called from an action in actions.js
// therefor, I am exporting it, and also, I am handing it dispatch
// so it will call store.dispatch once data is ready

export const fetchCardsFromFirebase = async (dispatch) => {
    const cardsCollection = collection(db, "cards");
    const cardsSnapshot = await getDocs(roomsCollection);
    const cards = roomsSnapshot.docs.map(doc => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id }));
    // here I can either explicitly dispatch an action 
    /*
    dispatch({
       type: CARDS_FETCHED         //this constant string will have to be imported
       payload: cards
    });
    */

    // or I can let an action in actions.js do the above:
    dispatch(cardsFetched(rooms));   //this function is imported from actions.js
}
```

## actions.js

```
import { FETCH_CARDS , CARDS_FETCHED } from "./types";
import { fetchCardsFromFirebase } from "../myFirebase";

export const fetchCards = () => async (dispatch) => {

    fetchCardsFromFirebase(dispatch);  // give firebase access to dispatch

    dispatch({
        type: FETCH_CARDS,
        payload: {message: "fetching cards... please wait"}
    });
};

const cardsFetched = (cards) => ({
   action: CARDS_FETCHED,
   payload: cards
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, this is a very old style of Redux - modern Redux does not use switch..case reducers or ACTION_TYPES and switching to [modern Redux](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux) will proably already save you 50% of your code.

That said, the official Redux Toolkit (RTK) also comes with RTK-Query, which is a data caching abstraction that should also work fine with firebase and will generate reducers, actions and even hooks automatically for you. (Hint: with firebase you will need to use `queryFn`). That would save you a lot more code as well.

I would recommend you to follow [the official Redux Tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts) which first shows modern Redux and in later chapters goes into RTK Query.